# Linux + PXE server + Silent Linux installation ( kick start linux ) from PXE server

Tags: linux

in my linux PXE server I have the following file lmd-Product_MS155

```
  lmd-Product_MS155 exist under /tftpboot/linux-install/pxelinux.cfg directory
```

this file lmd-Product_MS155 defined the menu for the user 
and from which location to take the ks.cfg and vmlinuz files,

In this case user can choose and install from the menu

One of the following linux's

```
 1. Linux-OS-5.5.1.0
 2. Linux-OS-5.5.1.1
```

my target is to automate the Linux installation in way that user will not get the menu and select the Linux version

I mean that:  user will write the required Linux version in some file/conf file 
and PXE server will run Linux installation without to ask user about Linux version – please advice how to do that

```
   remark -  PXE server IP - 129.18.210.47



   more  /tftpboot/linux-install/pxelinux.cfg/lmd-Product_MS155




   ######################################################
   MENU TITLE Linux Master Disk Product_MS155 

    LABEL Main Menu
    MENU LABEL Main Menu
    KERNEL menu.c32
    APPEND pxelinux.cfg/default
    #######################################################

    LABEL -
    MENU LABEL KS:
    MENU DISABLE

    LABEL   ALL IMAGES HERE ARE STANDARD INSTALLATION!



    LABEL   RedHat-Linux-OS-5.5.1.0
    KERNEL RedHat-Linux-OS-5.5.1.0/vmlinuz
    APPEND initrd=RedHat-Linux-OS-5.5.1.0/initrd.img ramdisk_size=6805 ksdevice=eth0 dns=129.18.210.47 ks=http://129.18.210.47/ks/ks_RedHat-Linux-OS-5.5.1.0.cfg



    LABEL   RedHat-Linux-OS-5.5.1.1
    KERNEL RedHat-Linux-OS-5.5.1.1/vmlinuz
    APPEND initrd=RedHat-Linux-OS-5.5.1.1/initrd.img ramdisk_size=6805 ksdevice=eth0 dns=129.18.210.47 ks=http://129.18.210.47/ks/ks_RedHat-Linux-OS-5.5.1.1.cfg
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to add at the top of the config file next:

```
PROMPT 0
TIMEOUT 1
DEFAULT RedHat-Linux-OS-5.5.1.1
```

Comment: you mean that need to add them in lmd-Product_MS155
file and before the LABEL string?

Comment: Yes. I mean add it in lmd-Product_MS155 file in the very top.

Comment: So did it helped?